# How To Edit Contact with identifier in ios 9 using CNContact framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontact, cncontactstore

i am using CNContact framework to retrive contacts from device and send to web using web services, but i want to edit contact using CNContact Framework but i don't know how to do...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the CNContactViewController.

```
let contactsViewController = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: contactToEdit)
contactsViewController.delegate = self
contactsViewController.title = "Edit contact"
contactsViewController.contactStore = CNContactStore()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(contactsViewController, animated: true)
```